# In material-ui how do i get a text input in an AppBar to the center?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Iv defined an app bar using material-ui [(app-bar-docs)](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar), and it includes a
`children` attribute which can be used to add content to it (the docs mention things like tabs can be added to the appbar). However, i want to have a text input inside the Appbar, but it ends up to the right,  after an `iconelementright` , how do i get it back to the  center? 
here is the code:

```
class AppBarExampleIconButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
  <AppBar
    title={<span style={styles.title}>Title</span>}
    onTitleTouchTap={handleTouchTap}
    iconElementRight={
      <DropDownMenu >
      <MenuItem value={"1"}  primaryText="Six"/>
      <MenuItem value={"2"} primaryText="Five" />
      <MenuItem value={"3"} primaryText="four"/>
      <MenuItem value={"4"} primaryText="three"/>
      <MenuItem value={"5"} primaryText="two"/>
      <MenuItem value={"6"} primaryText="one"/>
      </DropDownMenu>
       } >
   <div key={"21"}  _grid={{x: 2, y: 1, w: 6, h: 2}} > <AutoCompleteExampleNoFilter/> </div>
  </AppBar>);
  }
}
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image: appbar problem]

Comment: I can take a look if you point me to a working demo.

Comment: @HazardouS a sorta working fiddle is  here: https://jsfiddle.net/1zy37ef2/ ,  the view times out  and i have to click try again,  the code is  here: https://github.com/thebookworm101/nonex

Comment: Sorry, but its very difficult to work with the generated minified code. Would it be possible for you to share the code on github? I can run and debug at my end. I would need to play with the react components to debug this.

Comment: @HazardouS it was already there, look at my previous comment, it has the github link,