# How to get autoComplete/TextField close title in AppBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I want to have a search bar and login button in AppBar. The search Bar should be close to he title. So the AppBar shoulb like this in this order:

```
Title SearchBox         LoginButton
```

How should I do? This is the code :

```
import React from 'react'
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar'
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/lib/flat-button'
import BarAutoComplete from './auto-complete'

const styles={
  title:{
    cursor:'pointer',
  },

}

const AppBarExample=()=>(
     <AppBar       
      title={<span style={styles.title}>Title</span>}
      children={<div><BarAutoComplete/><FlatButton label="Search" /></div>}   

      iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Login" />} 
       />

      )
export default AppBarExample
```

With this code the search bar is after the login button.
This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394176/in-material-ui-how-do-i-get-a-text-input-in-an-appbar-to-the-center)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's the way the `AppBar` is coded, you can have a look at the source code here: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/app-bar.jsx#L329-L332

So a solution could have been to invert your elements and set your search bar as the `iconElementRight` and the login button as `children`, but sadly as the name and [the code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/app-bar.jsx#L287-L319) suggest `iconElementRight` is for an icon or flat button only. Anything else won't work.

The only thing I think you could do is create an issue on GitHub to ask them for an enhancement of the `AppBar`.

As last general advice, if you didn't do it in this case, when you ask yourself something about material-ui go look at the code. Their online documentation is sometimes missing a lot of stuff compared to what material-ui can really do.